# Using Google Spreadsheets QUERY to Filter

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have [the following google sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/171gWCMA5Db9sgpHplhRdIMkJFF2MkDNg6YfsONYAVDs/edit?usp=sharing) where:

- Col a= quantities
- Col b= product codes, which i´ve split between C and H.

I want to know the quantity according to different "filters"... this filters are the fields between C11 and H11, and they are optional. There are 6 possible filters.

It works using =QUERY formula located in H12 and it returns the sum of quantity values where the filters match...

BUT there´s the possibility of leaving a filter empty to get "all"...

the query is as follows:

=QUERY(A1:H7, "select sum(A) where C contains '"&C11&"' and lower(D) contains lower('"&D11&"') and E contains '"&E11&"' and lower(F) contains lower('"&F11&"') and lower(G) contains lower('"&G11&"') and lower(H) contains lower('"&H11&"') ",-1)

My problem is with the match type: where C **contains** '"&C11&"' and...

instead of using "contains" it should compare using "**matches**". this way it would count like it should, **but** then it won´t accept empty filters.

How can I get it to count only if the field is filled??

What´s wrong with the filter right now? It´s counting "4" matches because model matches "1" happens when model is 1 or 21, also with column D where i´m looking for value X and is also counting value XN as it contains "X". if formula is changed to "matches" instead of "contains", it won´t allow me to leave it blank.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Karl_S formula is great, but it does not sum the quantities in column A. Adapting his approach to SUMIFS seems to do it:

```
=SUMIFS(A2:A7,C2:C7, IF(ISBLANK(C11), "<>" ,C11),D2:D7, IF(ISBLANK(D11), "<>" ,D11),E2:E7, IF(ISBLANK(E11), "<>" ,E11),F2:F7, IF(ISBLANK(F11), "<>" ,F11),G2:G7, IF(ISBLANK(G11), "<>" ,G11),H2:H7, IF(ISBLANK(H11), "<>" ,H11))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this formula instead:

```
=COUNTIFS(C2:C7, IF(ISBLANK(C11), "<>" ,C11), D2:D7, IF(ISBLANK(D11), "*",D11), E2:E7, IF(ISBLANK(E11), "<>",E11), F2:F7, IF(ISBLANK(F11), "*",F11), G2:G7, IF(ISBLANK(G11), "*",G11), H2:H7, IF(ISBLANK(H11), "*",H11))
```

If one of the options is blank, it will match all items in that column.  Otherwise it should do an exact match.